MRI contrast power injectors
Would a question about MRI contrast power injectors (a pump) be on topic in the Engineering.SE, what should the tags be?

Is it true that with power injectors a good 2-3ml of the drug used
(e.g 30ml of Gadobutrol solution) in MRI as a contrast agent is lost,
how efficient is a device that wastes as much as 10% of the drug?

I am thinking of tags like
Mechanical-engineering
Fluid-mechanics
Applied-mechanics
Mechanisms
Design
Pumps

Just do your best with the tags. No need to obsess over it.
You have already asked a question about this here:
MRI contrast power injectors
The question could definitely be on topic, as long as it is about the design of the injector. As I wrote on the question, it would be much better if you included technical details about the injectors you speak of.

The problem is that I can't get these technical details (almost noone knows and more importantly noone is interested the management of the hospital could give me the information after a formal request they could just check the manual instead they will say why does it even matter to me and reject or ignore my request). And the question is not specific about a single model but about the philosophy/engineering/design. Do you get as much as 10% just because you didn't flush the lines into the examinee? Why even design them that way?

@GeorgeNtoulos I searched "mri contrast power injector" and literally the first link is a company that sells them. And there are several more on the first page. Call those companies, email them, leave voicemails. Tell them you want to buy one if necessary. You will eventually get some info.

Won't I detract from the generality I wanted in my question/answers? I want an answer "without loss of generality" won't providing a finite number of specific models detract from it? https://www.guerbet.com/media/sy3dvt1s/gu01240017_guerbet_optistar_sellsheet_20240403.pdf I just found the specifications of a model but I don't know if that is what is used (and I want a general answer not specific to this model)

It will provide necessary context for engineers who do not already work with these devices (aka almost all of us).

I already edited my question accordingly. Hope it is better now.
